How to Locate and Interact with Elements Inside Shadow DOM and iframe in Selenium?
I am trying to scrape a website which has Shadow DOM and iframe. As you can see in the image I can't find any selector for the Shadow DOM so I can get to iframe.
HTML elements
How do I locate Shadow DOM (either CSS Selector, XPATH, etc.)?
The page I am trying to scrape is: scrape.do
P.S. I was aiming for the iframe in this way:
iframe = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'cf-chl-widget-3kwf9'))
)


The first page you're seeing is actually the Cloudflare Turnstile CAPTCHA that is blocking you from reaching the page that you actually want to go to. It can be bypassed easily with SeleniumBase UC Mode:
from seleniumbase import Driver

driver = Driver(uc=True)
try:
    driver.uc_open_with_reconnect("dashboard.scrape.do/login", 4)
    driver.uc_gui_click_captcha()
    driver.type("#username", "Hello!")
    driver.sleep(3)
finally:
    driver.quit()

If running on Linux, you'll definitely need to use the SB() format instead, which includes more functionality and a special virtual display:
from seleniumbase import SB

with SB(uc=True) as sb:
    url = "dashboard.scrape.do/login"
    sb.uc_open_with_reconnect(url, 4)
    sb.uc_gui_click_captcha()
    sb.type("#username", "Hello!")
    sb.sleep(3)


It works, but now I have an issue when passing the email in the driver.type("#username", "example@gmail.com"). It writes example than some some random stuff without @ and then gmail.com. What is the issue?

That sounds odd. I'm not seeing that on my end. Maybe a language setting you have set, or a shortcut? You can call regular selenium methods via the driver or sb.driver too. See if those work.
